# How to wrap an asynchronous function in a promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, pixi.js

I want to wrap an asynchronous function in a promise so that it can run synchronously. I need to do this because I need to retrieve a result that depends on the asynchronous function before continuing with the execution of my program.

Here is my relevant code:

```
export abstract class OperationElement extends Sprite {

    private imagePath;

    abstract setPosition(mousePosition?, backgroundHeight?, backgroundWidth?) : void;

    loadTexture(){
         var _texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(this.imagePath);
         this.texture = _texture;
         console.log(this.height);
    }

    setImagePath(path : string){
         this.imagePath = path;
    }
}
```

The part that runs async is the line `var _texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(this.imagePath);`

When the texture is loaded, I can get the height of the texture. I need the height of the texture before I can continue execution of my program. How can I wrap this with a promise so that it runs synchronously?

I've taken a look at some other questions around here, the most relevant had a bunch of downvoted and out of date answers so I shy away from that.

Comment: What does `fromImage` return?

Comment: @Phil, `fromImage` returns a `Texture` object, which is just an object built into pixi.js. You can read up on it here if you're interested: http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Texture.html. The most important thing is that I need that `Texture` object to be returned before I continue execution of my program.

Comment: `PIXI.Texture.fromImage` is already synchronously return the `Texture` isn't it? You don't need promise or am I missing something?

Comment: @Hereblur, no, `PIXI.Texture.fromImage` returns the texture asynchronously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
loadTexture():Promise<PIXI.Texture> {  
     return new Promise<PIXI.Texture>((resolve, reject) => {
         var image = new Image();
         image.src = this.imagePath;
         image.onload = () => {
             console.log(image.height);
             this.texture = PIXI.Texture.from(image);
             resolve(this.texture);
         }
         image.onerror = e => reject(e);
     });
}
```

Comment: What is the `Image` object in this case? It's not a pixi.js object, so is it really needed?

Comment: @PythonNewb it's `HTMLImageElement`, html builtin object. Since image is loaded asynchronously in web, you will need to wrap it around to get its size (only available after loaded). And `PIXI.Texture.fromImage` is synchronous, It handles the asynchronous loading process internally.

Comment: I think I understand. Where is the texture being assigned? Should it be done within the resolve function? Like `resolve(var _texture = PIXI.Texture.from(image); this.texture = _texture)` ?

Comment: @PythonNewb , see edited answer. resolve is like a `callback`, while only for success results, and reject for errors. so `resolve(var _texture = PIXI.Texture.from(image); this.texture = _texture)` won't work.

Comment: Thank you. What does the line `resolve(this.texture)` do?

Comment: @PythonNewb, it resolves the `Promise` from `pending` state. once you call `await loadTexture()`, code halts execution, until `Promise` is resolved. it's just like a callback function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @PythonNewb, try `new PIXI.Texture(new PIXI.BaseTexture(image))`. There is something wrong with `PIXI.js` code, it handles `HTMLImageElement`, while it declares not taking it. http://pixijs.download/release/docs/core_textures_Texture.js.html#line373 described it

Comment: I see. I have tried your code, I get the error `Argument of type 'HTMLImageElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | BaseTexture | HTMLCanvasElement | HTMLVideoElement'` I think using a `HTMLImageElement` will not work in this case.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I think it should be brought up in the pixi github repo. I tried `this.texture = new PIXI.Texture(new PIXI.BaseTexture(image));` and it seems to have worked, I'll test for a bit more to make sure before accepting your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132246/discussion-between-pythonnewb-and-qiaosen-huang).

Answer (score 2):

You just need a simple callback.

```
onTextureLoaded(){

    console.log( this.texture.height )
    this.texture.off('update', this.onTextureLoaded, this);

}

loadTexture(){
    var _texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(this.imagePath);
    this.texture = _texture;

    this.texture.on('update', this.onTextureLoaded, this);

}
```

Comment: This also works well. I wanted to avoid callbacks as they can quickly make code messy. For some reason, assigning the height to a class attribute in my `OperationElement` class and then trying to retrieve it results in an `undefined`, though